# How to get a shuffled result from DynamoDB?

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using nodejs to connect with DynamoDB and I'm in a position that I am suppose to render shuffle result on the page from AWS DynamoDB.

is there anyway to get shuffled result from DynamoDB directly or any efficient way to shuffle it on the server;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that by shuffled you mean to ask DynamoDB to return a random item from your table. In this case the answer is basically: no - there is no such functionality built-in.

However, if you design your partition & range key schema in such a way that you can easily pick a random element then you can do it client side from your query. Depending on the density of data in the table this may require multiple queries to actually return a result but it can be done.

Let's say your results are of the form  ABC-123 where ABC is a partition key and 123 is the range key value, then you could random partition key selection from the client and then try a query on that key. If the key returns some data then you can select one of the items at random. Again, based on density of data in each partition you may use a second random threshold for the query.

I hope this helps.